# Sum a list of BigIntegers

Tags: c#, syntax, sum, biginteger

I've looked all over but can't figure this out. How do you sum a list of BigIntegers?

```
Using System.Numerics;
Using System.Linq;

List<BigInteger> bigInts = new List<BigInteger>();
BigInteger sum = bigInts.Sum();             // doesn't work
BigInteger sum = bigInts.Sum<BigInteger>(); // doesn't work
BigInteger sum = bigInts.Sum(x => x);       // doesn't work
```

Do you have to do this?

```
BigInteger sum = new BigInteger(0);
foreach(BigInteger bigint in bigInts)
    sum += bigint;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) function is more general version of Sum:

```
var bigInts = new List<System.Numerics.BigInteger>(); 
bigInts.Add(new System.Numerics.BigInteger(1));

var result = bigInts.Aggregate((currentSum, item)=> currentSum + item));
```

Comment: Or just `bigInts.Aggregate(BigInteger.Add)` :)

Comment: Alexei, This is exactly what I used as soon as you put your answer, I looked up how to use Aggregate. @leppie, could you add some explanation how your magic works?

Comment: @jb.: It is just a delegate, referencing the `BigInteger.Add` method.

Answer (score 19):

```
var sum = bigInts.Aggregate(BigInteger.Add);
```

Aggregate gets a delegate to a method which gets two BigIntegers and return a BigInteger. It uses a default BigInteger as initial value (0), and goes over each BigInteger, invoking BigInteger.Add with the previous result (0 would be previous result in the first time - also called 'seed') and the current element.

Comment: Lol. Likewise! What question are you on now? ;P

Comment: The initial value is not really necessary when dealing with `Add`.

Comment: @leppie Thanks for the note. Fixed.

Comment: @jb. Very nice. Are you doing them by order?

Comment: @jb. Friend request sent. Lets not spam SO with small talk. :)

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Your explanation is incorrect. There must be at least 1 value in the list. In that case, only that value is returned, else `Add` will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method on generic lists to do the addition:

```
var bigInts = new List<BigInteger>();

BigInteger sum = 0;
bigInts.ForEach(x => sum += x);
```

Comment: I thought of this, but it still requires an extra BigInteger. And I'd have to do `.ToList()` if I'm in an `IEnumerable<BigInteger>`. (Which I am, but forgot to mention)

Comment: Ah, well then, that makes a slight difference. (-:

Answer (score 0):

As Alexei said Aggregate is the more general from of sum.
Presented below is an extension method.

```
public BigInteger static Sum(IEnumerable<BigInteger> this lst)
{
    return lst.Aggregate(BigInteger.Zero, (acc, next)=> acc.Add(next));
}
```

I haven't tested this, and my C# might be getting a little rusty.
but the idea should be sound:
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx#Y0

Comment: You might want to have a return type and return something.

Comment: Oh i see while i was typing this @Alexei Levenkov, updated his answer to incude an example.
great minds think alike

Comment: leppie, Ah yes. Too much using F# for me. forgot about those. Fixed now

Comment: Don't you have to do `this.Aggregate(...)` ?

Comment: @jb.: I fixed the syntax. `lst.Aggregate(BigInteger.Add)` will also work.

Comment: Apparently my C@ was rustier than i thought.

Comment: @Oxinabox you know you're rusty when you can't even spell "C#" right. haha :)